# Sending data to FPGA

Tags: fpga, xilinx, input, tcp-ip, bram

If I send 160bit message to an FPGA using TCP/IP

Do I need to store the message in BRAM first ?

Not sure how the FPGA receives data and gets to work on it yet.

Comment: An FPGA *does not* receive messages unless you build or instantiate the capability to do so. And TCP/IP conventionally implies a processor running software, not just FPGA fabric...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, most FPGAs will have many more than 160 flip-flops that you can use. Store the data anyplace you like.

Comment: Also, quite a lot of messages can be processed as they arrive and don't need to be stored at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to have a look at these [Ethernet cores](https://www.fpga-cores.com/cores/).
These do all Ethernet and TCP without processor and are very easy to use.